# Could not load file or assembly 'XamlAnimatedGif, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animated-gif

I was searching for a method to load a gif icon on my tab item, but I didn't get what I needed. I tried this library: [XamlAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif).

In fact, I choose the latest version and installed its Nuget package. I wrote this code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject"
    xmlns:gif="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="TabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged" BorderBrush="LightGray"  Grid.Row="1" >
            <TabControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" ClipToBounds="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <WrapPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Panel.ZIndex ="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,0" IsItemsHost="true"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TabControl.Template>
    
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel Width="150">
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    BorderThickness="0.0"  Width="9" Height="9" Padding="0" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            <Image Width="9" Height="9"></Image>
                        </Button>
    
                        <!--<Image  x:Name="BusyIcon" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="../icons/Loading_icon.gif" Width="9" Height="9" Visibility="Visible"></Image>-->
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />
    
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
    
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run my application, I get this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XamlAnimatedGif, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I prevent this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML is wrong, since you mix two different projects.

- [WpfAnimatedGif](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/WpfAnimatedGif) - Old, *WPF specific* version of the library.
- [XamlAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif) - New version of the library.

You use the XML namespace of the new version with `https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif`, but the attachted property `AnimatedSource` of the old version. The assembly is most probably not found because you installed the package of the old version.

### Old WpfAnimatedGif Version

1. Install the [WpfAnimatedGif](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfAnimatedGif) package.
2. Add this XML namespace:

   ```
   `xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
   ```
3. Specify the GIF image using the `AnimatedSource` property of the `ImageBehavior`.

   ```
   <Image  x:Name="BusyIcon" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="../icons/Loading_icon.gif"/>
   ```

### New XamlAnimatedGif Version

1. Install the [XamlAnimatedGif](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlAnimatedGif/) package.
2. Add this XML namespace:

   ```
   xmlns:gif="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif"
   ```
3. Specify the GIF image using the `SourceUri` property of the `AnimationBehavior`.

   ```
   <Image  x:Name="BusyIcon" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="../icons/Loading_icon.gif"/>
   ```

Comment: I did the same steps you mentionned to install XamlAnimatedGif ( new version ) but I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @JuniorDev13 This is not reproducible with what you posted. Locally tested, both the old and the new version work as expected.

Comment: I didn't know why this happens only with me , I'm sure that it's the same

Comment: I have the same problem like JuniorDev

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had both versions, WpfAnimatedGif and XamlAnimatedGif installed; I deleted the old version, restarted Visual Studio and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

@JuniorDev13 I solved this issue by adding
`AnimationBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(imgCircle, System.Windows.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior.Forever)` in .cs file

I think the issue was not specifying `using XamlAnimatedGif;` namespace to .cs file